# How can i fire button click event to call another function?

Tags: android, button, event-handling

I have 3 buttons, and when I click one of them they are opening my contact list. Then I pick someone and I get a phone number, and I want to set that number to a button's text. My question is this: How can I handle which button is pressed in that function. `Performclick` did not work for me.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    //for get number and name from contacts
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        number = c.getString(0);
                        name=c.getString(1);

                        if(Number1.performClick()){
                            Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else if(Number2.performClick()){
                            Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
                        }
                        else if(Number3.performClick()){
                            Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
                        }

                }

                    }
                    finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what do you mean by "set number to button".
If you just want to set a button's caption, use setText(CharSequence)
method.

Comment: give id to button in xml view and check it while `perfrClick`..

Comment: Bu perform click like soft click.Means programmatically.Do you know any trıgger event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
//..
int currentButtonId;
//..
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        currentButtonId = R.id.button1;
        button1Clicked();
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        currentButtonId = R.id.button2;
        button2Clicked();
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        currentButtonId = R.id.button3;
        button3Clicked();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (currentButtonId) {
    case R.id.button1:
        fromButton1();
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        fromButton2();
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        fromButton3();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send different-2 `request code` while calling contact list, and put check against request code in `onAcitivityResult()`.

Or you can create a `static int` variable to hold the clicked button id, and set result as per this variable.